# Rails5 - creating a contact form (receiving mails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, mailer

I am trying to do an application with a contact page. With this page, I wanted to give an opportunity to the users to send mails to the main mail account of the application.

I have found documentation about `mailers` but it's about 'welcoming mail' in general. (and I am new to Rails, I don't understand some parts).

I would like to use Rails mailers instead of gems to do the contact page.

My question is this; do you know an article that I can follow/check to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send emails using Rails its 2 steps:

#### Step 1:

Email itself and it's content and you can check [here in rails documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) for sending emails using Rails only Section 2.1 is what you need

#### Step 2:

Configure the mail server you will be using to do the actual sending for the email, in this [article](https://hixonrails.com/ruby-on-rails-tutorials/ruby-on-rails-action-mailer-configuration/) it contain almost every possible option to do that

Comment: Hello again, I am going through your suggestion but I have a problem. I am at the end of step 1, I have built the mailer and it's working. I have checked it via letter_oppener. My current problem now is I cannot send any mail. I cannot find the correct settings for SMTP. I have tried with gmail and mailgun but I am getting ´end of file reached´ error and there is not any other line about the error.

Comment: What domain you are sending from

Comment: I am using mailgun

Comment: I succeeded to generate emails for welcoming new users and sending them via Gmail. Now, I am passing the step2. I wanted to inform, so you don't need to spend your time:) Thank you!